# Getting friends status message privacy setting

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, status, privacy

Is there any way to get the privacy setting of a friends status message that appears on my newsfeed? When using the graph api like descriped in [this](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10894414/getting-the-privacy-setting-of-a-status-message) post, only my own status messages have a priacy field that contains data, in all other cases the field is empty:

`"privacy": { "value": "" }`

I also tried to retrieve the privacy data with fql (stream), but with the same result as above.

Maybe I'm missing any other api calls that return the data or any known workarounds. If it is just not possible, please tell me.